# PHP. Requirements. For creating a live video streaming

Tags: php, video-streaming, requirements

Our aim is to create a live video streaming site for each individual paid *registered* user only by php platform.

I need video camera to take videos and i want to know function flow.I dont know where i have to start.

What are all things needed? Especially live video uploading using ordinary video camera. I have found http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=PHP+Live+Streaming This is the site, i exactly needed. Unfortunately but its camera option only includes "webcam only". I would like input video camera instead of webcam.

1. I need suggestions for requirements to create the site.
2. I need to stream live video for each paid user. That includes flash player content.
3. Uploading and video control by admin side. Only live links is shared to customers.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is nothing about PHP, but something about JAVA.

You can use Red5 as media server, and users watch videos via flash player. You also can take videos with flash.

Answer (score 0):

Found an interesting link on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

And Symfony 2.1 is going to handle streamed responses: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response, but is not stable yet.